# Errors in tutorial03_rlib

Tags: flow-project

when running the tutorial03_rllib, I faced some errors.

At step 4.2 (initializing Flow) the errors are:

```
2020-05-07 21:43:00,585 INFO node.py:498 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2020-05-07_21-43-00_584118_78776/logs.
2020-05-07 21:43:00,696 INFO services.py:409 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:50709 to respond...
2020-05-07 21:43:00,808 INFO services.py:409 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:44844 to respond...
2020-05-07 21:43:00,811 INFO services.py:809 -- Starting Redis shard with 3.44 GB max memory.
2020-05-07 21:43:00,825 INFO node.py:512 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2020-05-07_21-43-00_584118_78776/logs.
2020-05-07 21:43:00,827 WARNING services.py:1330 -- WARNING: The default object store size of 5.15 GB will use more than 50% of the available memory on this node (5.98 GB). Consider setting the object store memory manually to a smaller size to avoid memory contention with other applications.
2020-05-07 21:43:00,828 INFO services.py:1475 -- Starting the Plasma object store with 5.15 GB memory using /tmp.
```

At step 4.4 (Running experiments) a lot of errors processing events (as you can see in the attached screenshots), but the algorithm execution terminates.

How can I face these problems/errors/warnings?

```
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]
[enter image description here][4]
[enter image description here][5]
[enter image description here][6]
[enter image description here][7]




[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvdUT.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuJbo.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIjpO.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fj2q.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bei5.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pZaZ.png
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSP4V.png
```